# Syncing data from iphone to the server Datetime question

Tags: iphone

I want sync data from iphone to the webs server. My question is how can I know which data is new? the only way I see this is by making a datafield for each record on the server and the iPhone, but how about if the Iphone user is in a different timezone or his datetime is different from the server datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all of your dates in GMT on both the server and device.  There are several methods for getting GMT easily in Objective-C.  The device will determine time-zone based on location.  If you need to convert to local time, you can get the date by using the NSTimeZoneClass:

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]]
```

Check out the docs on [Date and Time Programming](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html) for additional assistance.